# Using bootstrapping to compare full and sample datasets

Tags: r

This is a fairly complicated situation, so I'll try to succinctly explain but feel free to ask for clarification.

I have several datasets of biological data that vary significantly in sample size (e.g., 253-1221 observations/dataset). I need to estimate individual breeding parameters and compare them (for a different analysis), but because of the large sample size differences, I took a sub-set of data from each dataset so the sample sizes were equal for each comparison. For example, the smallest dataset had 253 observations, so for all the others I used the following code

`AT_EABL_subset <- Atlantic_EABL[sample(1:nrow(Atlantic_EABL), 253,replace=FALSE),]`

to take a subset of 253 observations from the full dataset (in this case AT_EABL originally had 1,221 observations).

It's now suggested that I use bootstrapping to check if the parameter estimates from my subsets are similar to the full dataset estimates. I'm looking for code that will run, say, 200 iterations of the above subset data ***and*** calculate the average of the coefficients so I can compare them to the coefficients from my model with the full dataset. I found a site that uses the sample function to achieve this (https://towardsdatascience.com/bootstrap-regression-in-r-98bfe4ff5007), but when I get to this portion of the code

```
    c(sample_coef_intercept, model_bootstrap$coefficients[1])
  
   sample_coef_x1 <-
    c(sample_coef_x1, model_bootstrap$coefficients[2])
}
```

I get
`Error: $ operator not defined for this S4 class`

Below is the code I'm using. I don't know if I'm getting the above error because of the type of model I'm running (glmer vs. lm used in the link), or if there's a different function that will give me the data I need. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

```
sample_coef_intercept <- NULL
sample_coef_x1 <- NULL


for (i in 1:2) {
  boot.sample = AT_EABL_subset[sample(1:nrow(AT_EABL_subset), nrow(AT_EABL_subset), replace = FALSE), ]
  model_bootstrap <- glmer(cbind(YOUNG_HOST_TOTAL_ATLEAST,CLUTCH_SIZE_HOST_ATLEAST-YOUNG_HOST_TOTAL_ATLEAST)~as.factor(YEAR)+(1|LatLong),binomial,data=boot.sample)}

sample_coef_intercept <-
  c(sample_coef_intercept, model_bootstrap$coefficients[1])

sample_coef_x1 <-
  c(sample_coef_x1, model_bootstrap$coefficients[2])
```

Comment: You could just use the `boot` package as per here to help you do this for you. https://www.statology.org/bootstrapping-in-r/

Comment: @Phil the package you suggest may work but takes repeated samples with replacement. I need to run a pre-selected subset of data (with unique observations) multiple times and find the average of the slopes and intercept